# Search form model(s)

Tags: backbone.js

I have to design a search form and display the results. I am having some difficulties finalizing the models/collections to be used.

I have a few fields which acts as filters. These fields are select boxes where multiple items can be selected. After an item has been selected from a field, I need to call the API which will return a list of results with this filter and also all the remaining filter options for the other fields based on the first filter.

What I am confused is how should I go about this. Should every select box be a model? Because the options for each select box will be changing.

About the results,
I am thinking that results should be a collection. But given that there is only one API endpoint here, I am confused which model should hold the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your API is actually returning a collection of results, I'd keep the filter parameters in a model, and while submitting search request, create the collection `URL` dynamically based on the filter model attributes.

You can go the other way, send the request from model itself, then in `parse` set results from response to the collection and remove it from model, but it seems more hacky than dynamically creating collection `URL`